# Is there a word for the value that you compare against a threshold value?

Tags: vocabulary

I am writing some software where I count some values and compare it to a threshold. Then if it is below the threshold the value will be highlighted.

Is there a specific word for the value that gets counted / compared to the threshold?

Comment: Are you looking for "*measurement*", "*observstion*", etc, or even something generic like "*data poin t*"?

Comment: Yep, measurement, observation, parameter, data point ... whatever best fits the data being observed and the terminology used elsewhere.  The threshold is secondary to the value being compared -- it wouldn't have any significance without that value.

Comment: Any value that may or may not fulfil some criterion (the criterion here is reaching the threshold) can be qualified as a *candidate*. You could happily refer to *candidate values*.

Comment: An example or two would be very helpful.

Comment: See also [Terms for parts of a comparative](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/167575/what-are-the-terms-for-the-parts-of-a-comparative)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a term that specifically means "a value that is compared to a threshold" (as opposed to simply a *measurement* or *counter*), I doubt you will find one.

However a common term for a value that is used to measure or count something is ["metric"](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/metric?s=t)

> **noun**  Often, metrics. a standard for measuring or evaluating something, especially one that uses figures or statistics: "new metrics for gauging an organization’s diversity;" "pretty good by any metric."

Comment: Isn't this more like a synonym for the threshold, not a name for the value that you're comparing against it?

Comment: No not at all. A metric is a measure, not a threshold.

Answer (score 0):

When you're comparing values against a threshold, it would appear you are devising a tiny (boolean) function/expression. So the value that gets compared would be an ***argument*** to the function/expression performing the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

A term for value above a threshold value is "value added."

If the value is *below* the threshold value, the "value added" is *negative*.

Answer (score 0):

As programmers we refer to this as a *[comparand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36674021/what-are-the-academic-names-for-the-left-and-right-operands-in-binary-relational)*, an operand in a comparison operation.

Strictly speaking the threshold value is also a comparand.  But it already has *threshold* as a more specific apellation.

Answer (score -1):

Could the term you are looking for be ***below par***, the 'threshold' being considered 'par'.

I think that nowadays *par* is used well beyond the golf course. We also use the metaphor *par for the course* for all sorts of things. *Par* is generally seen as a standard for something - which could possibly apply to your *threshold*.

Though I appreciate that the two words are not identical in meaning, they do have synonymous qualities.

Comment: This describes the relation of the value measured to the threshold, it's not a name for the measurement itself.

Answer (score -2):

The term is **cutoff**.

*"If the value is lower than the cutoff, it is highlighted"*

Comment: "Cuttoff" is he threshold.